# How to position facebook "like" button on website

Tags: html, css

I'm Trying a facebook like button on a website in a certain place. I tried using a div position it on a certain part of the page and move along with the layout as the browser is resized, but it's not working. The button stays in the left corner of the page.

How can I move it?

Here is the portion of the code and where I placed the div

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=133207363431387&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://notchtheguru.com" send="true" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" colorscheme="dark" font="arial"></fb:like> 
</head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
body {
    background-image: url(images/NotchTheGuru_bg.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
}

#bodyContent {
    position: relative;

}

#fbdiv {
    position: relative;
    left: 1017px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}



</style> 
<body> 

<div id="fbdiv"><div id="fb-root"></div></div> 
<center> 
<div id="bodyContent">
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it Out. Simple fix.

I placed the div in the body, but didn't actually include the "fb:like" code inside the div.

I always spend time on stupid stuff that I should have realized from the start smh.

thanks for the answers.